# Creating lists based on two conditions

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, append

I am trying to create lists based on data from users.  The data is a 16 question survey, and so I want to split the data into a list of the 16 answers, or a list that is just `answers = ['No data available`]  My code so far is shown below.

```
studentanswers = []
contains_data = False
temp = []  
for i in answers:
if i == 'No data available':
    if contains_data:
        studentanswers.append(temp)
        temp = []
        studentanswers.append([i])
        contains_data = False
    else:
        studentanswers.append([i])
else:
    contains_data = True
    if len(temp) < 16:
        temp.append(i)
    else:
        studentanswers.append(temp)
        temp = []
        contains_data = False
```

However, as I iterate, the data gets off the correct count, and some of the data gets assigned to the wrong user.  For example, question 16 for student 1 will become question 1 for student 2.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Please share example input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Try something along these lines:

```
while answers:
    if answers[0] = 'No data available':
        studentanswers.append(['No data available'])
        answers = answers[1:]
    else:
       studentanswers.append(answers[:16])
       answers = answers[16:]
```

Comment: This solution only divides the data when 'No data available' appears.  Would there be a way to create a list when 'No data available' appears, and also create a list after 16 items are in present in a list?

Comment: It also create a list when 'no data available' does not appear. look at the line - studentanswers.append(answers[:16])

Comment: I had some mistakes on my end, I cleaned them up and this worked perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Your question is unclear, if i got it right, you want a list of the answers of each student.

If this is the case then this should suffice:

```
studentanswers = list()
for x in range(len(answers)/16):
    sudentsanswers.append(list(answers[y*16:(y+1)*16])
```

This assumes you have 16 answers for every student.

Edit, i just saw your other comment, this will work:

```
studentanswers = list()
studentanswers.append(list())
c = int(0)
for x in range(len(answers)):
    if (c<16 && x  != "No data available"):
        studentanswers[len(studentanswers)-1].append(x)
        c+=1
    else:
        c=0
        studentanswers.append(list())
        studentanswers[len(studentanswers)-1].append(x)
        if x == "No data available":
            studentanswers.append(list())
```